Create datetimeoffset from columns datetime and bigint
I have two columns on my table @dateTimeColumn datetime and @timezoneOffsetColumn bigint.
I need to convert these two columns into one column of type datetimeoffset. How can I do it in SQL Server?
@timezoneOffsetColumn is in format: DateTime.Ticks.



dateTimeColumn
timeZoneOffsetColumn
dateTimeWithTimeZoneColumn




2024-09-10 21:00:00.000
108000000000
2024-09-10 21:00:00.000 +03:00



I know this method:
UPDATE @myTable
SET @dateTimeWithTimeZoneColumn = CONVERT(datetime2, @dateTimeColumn) AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'

but I don't understand how to make it work with my offset

As 108000000000 represents Z+03:00, so we do 108000000000 / 3 which is 36,000,000,000 so 36billion represents 1 hour - so that looks like a (Windows style?) 10MHz tick value...

You wrote thast "@timezoneOffsetColumn is a format: DateTime.Ticks" - but the .Ticks property is not intended to be used like this because it doesn't represent anything w.r.t UTC (unless you had DateTimeKind.Utc but your post doesn't say that) -  (for example, it ignores leap-seconds). Can you tell us more about where/how this data came from?

See datetimeoffsetfromparts

The "hard part" is probably converting 108000000000 to the relevant hours and seconds, however, that's just division and modulo.

There's also TODATETIMEOFFSET() which seems tailor-made for this.

For the above function, you can calculate the offset in minutes as timeZoneOffsetColumn / 600000000 (10,000,000 ticks/second and 60 seconds per minute).

Okay, thank you. It works.
UPDATE @myTable
SET @dateTimeWithTimeZoneColumn = TODATETIMEOFFSET(@dateTimeColumn, @timeZoneOffsetColumn / 600000000)


This desing needs some fixing. The DateTime.Ticks docs you linked to say that 1 tick is 100ns, when timezones are half-hour multiples. TODATETIMEOFFSET accepts minutes which is more than enough. Using datetimeoffset would be even better.  The best option, resilient to daylight rule changes, is local time plus timezone name in a separate field. This way, if Russia or Egypt decide to change their summer time rules with just a couple of months warning again, you won't have to go and change all offsets.

when timezones are half-hour multiples? That is an incorrect assumption. There are multiple time zones that are neither hourly nor half-hourly.

@AlwaysLearning With timezones that differ by half an hour everything also works correctly. I don't know any other timezones

select * from sys.time_zone_info where current_utc_offset NOT LIKE '%[03]0' will show the outlying quarter-hour timezones. Although time zone offset could be more efficiently stored as minutes in a smallint, there is nothing particularly wrong with storing ticks in a bigint - it's just overkill. Typical databases designs are full of opportunities for small data type improvements (smalldatetime over datetime,tinyint over int, UTF-8 varchar vs nvarchar), if we needed to optimize out every byte.
